# How to add a 'at least X' in a solver solution - Excel

Tags: excel, solver

I've developed a solver solution in my excel document where it automatically selects the lowest price in a SUMPRODUCT situation.

To make everything simpler, there is a picture of the actual spreadsheet below. Take into account that =SOMARPRODUTO is actually =SUMPRODUCT in english.

[image]

What i'm currently trying to add and haven't been successfull yet, is making a restriction based on another cell.
For example, the solver can only consider solutions from the row [B4:AU4] that have a number higher than the one in the cell [$AW$7].

Perhaps i need to make a if condition and then use the SUMPRODUCT formula?

If the question is not explicit as it should be, please let me know and i'll add more information to it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this `=SOMARPRODUTO((B4:AU4>=$AW$3)*B5:AU5,B6:AU6)`

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: I guess not. Here is why: in your formula you say that B3:AU3 must be higher than the value in AW3, and then you multiply it by B4:AU4,B5:AU5.
I just want to make a condition where it considers values in B4:AU4 that are higher than the cell AW3.
And then it does a SUMPRODUCT(B5:AU5;B6:AU6) with the admited values in the row B4:AU4.

Comment: @Anna - Fernando's concept seems correct, just shifted by a row, try like this: `=SOMARPRODUTO((B4:AU4>=$AW$3)*B5:AU5,B6:AU6)` - note that the format of AW3 needs to match B4:AU4 for a valid comparison

Comment: Barry is right. I assumed your %s were in row 3, based on the screenshot. Edited.

Comment: Thanks barryhoudini and Fernando. Forgot to had the same format on AW3. Solved :)

Answer (score 0):

You should use a boolean statement to solve your issue,

```
 =IF(CONDITION,PASSED,FAILED)
```

Basically, just add your SUM function to the PASSED section and your cell verification ($AW$7) to your condition.